# Is there Range Type partitioning in Hadoop/Hive like there is in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive, partitioning

I need to compare partitioning in Hadoop compared to Oracle. I could find analogical Partitioning types such as List Partitioning and Hash Partitioning in Hadoop in terms of dynamic partitioning and Bucketing similar to Oracle.
Is there any method to create Range Partitioning in Hadoop/Hive?

Answer (score 0):

No Hadoop does not support Range Partition, below are the supported partition-er in Hadoop.

1. HashPartitioner
2. BinaryPartitioner
3. KeyFieldBasedPartitioner
4. TotalOrderPartitioner